# What meaning does phrase "separate classes for boys and girls" carry

Tags: meaning, expressions

I was passing past a school where it said "separate classes for boys and girls", meaning separate classes for boys and separate classes for girls. Does this phrase "separate classes for boys and girls" carry this meaning, if not how can it be said in one phrase.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience "separate classes for boys and girls" could be misconstrued if pondered upon but the sentence does carry the meaning;
"separate classes for boys and separate classes for girls"

An alternative phrase satisfying verbal pedantry may be;
"Boys and girls are separated into classes according to kind." but is perhaps archaic and may not be understood at all by non native speakers.

A more modern version, substituting "kind" with "sex" or "gender" might also raise some difficulties.